# Continuity of the integral depending on parameter

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

How to prove the function $F(y)$ is continuous?

$$F(y)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\pi/4}(x^2+y^2+1)} \, dx$$

Comment: Have you tried just using $\delta-\epsilon$ definition?

Comment: The integrals $F_n(y) = \int_{1/n}^1 \frac{dx}{x^{\pi/4}(x^2+y^2+1)}$ are continuous for $y \in \mathbb{R}$ since the integrand is continuous on $[1/n,1] \times \mathbb{R}$.  The improper integral is uniformly convergent by the Weierstrass test, and this implies that $F_n(y) \to F(y) =  \int_{0}^1 \frac{dx}{x^{\pi/4}(x^2+y^2+1)}$ uniformly and , hence, $F$ is continuous.

Comment: Also please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510)